# Database model for API usage monitoring

Tags: database-design

We want to design a database model for usage monitoring of our APIs per our consumer.

For e.g. we have CRUD APIs like Create, Read, Update and Delete.

We want to have a DB structure like this for usage monitoring.

[image]

So for each consumer id the counter for APIs are kept.

As per the above table consumer "1001" has per performed 10 create APIs till date.

Problem with this kind of table structure is that it won't scale because the APIs can be added/changed.  For example the X column can be anything or any numbers in the future . If changed then the DB has to be changed every time.

I am looking for some generic solution where DB modifications can be kept at minimal.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: You need a table with `consumer_id, api_name, counter` if a new API comes in, create a new row

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your comments...with your suggestion i see that the api differentiation happens on the row level and there will be multiple rows for each apis..one point to note is that i am using a columnar database not a rowstore..